# How do I configure VSCode to put Allman style braces on separate lines like C # but in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, c#, dart, visual-studio-code

for example if I write a code block like this

```
 if (age <18)
 {
     print ('You are minor');
 }
```

<! - end snippet ->

If I like the C # format so I want it
BUT
If I write a code in JavaScript, VSCode formats it like this:

```
 if (age <18) {
     alert ('You are minor');
 }
```

Even if I write it in Dart, VSCode automatically formats it as well like this:

```
 if (age <18) {
     print ('You are minor');
 }
```

How can I make it automatically every time I write a function or a method or a code block like the if else, how do I make the vs code automatically format me in the Allman style as I showed in the first block above, (This for any language programming you use)

Comment: No way to set it up out of the box. You can run `CTRL-K+F` though. FWIW, I'd just use JetBrains Rider.